# How to delete subdirectories of a directory that do not contain files of specific types?

Tags: batch-file, directory

How to delete all directories in a main directory that don't contain files with the extensions .flac .mp3 .m4a?

Many of the directories that need to be deleted are not empty, but do not contain those files.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the folder `C:\Temp\Test` contains following non hidden subfolders and files in those subfolders:

- **Folder 1**

  - File 1.txt
- **Folder 2**

  - File 2.mp3
- **Folder 3**

  - File 3.m4a
- **Folder 4**
- **Folder 5**

  - File 5.tmp
  - File 5.doc

The batch file to process those 5 subfolders of `C:\Temp\Test`:

```
@echo off
for /D %%D in ("C:\Temp\Test\*") do call :CheckFolder "%%D"
goto :EOF

:CheckFolder
for %%I in (flac mp3 m4a) do (
    if exist "%~1\*.%%I" (
        echo Folder %1 contains *.%%I file.
        goto :EOF
    )
)
echo Delete folder %1
echo rd /Q /S %1
goto :EOF
```

The batch file produces the output:

```
Delete folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 1"
rd /Q /S "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 1"
Folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 2" contains *.mp3 file.
Folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 3" contains *.m4a file.
Delete folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 4"
rd /Q /S "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 4"
Delete folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 5"
rd /Q /S "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 5"
```

It looks like the batch file is working as expected. So next step is removing `echo` from last but one line to really execute removing the folder with command **RD**. The batch output is now:

```
Delete folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 1"
Folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 2" contains *.mp3 file.
Folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 3" contains *.m4a file.
Delete folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 4"
Delete folder "C:\Temp\Test\Folder 5"
```

The folder `C:\Temp\Test` contains now only:

- **Folder 2**

  - File 2.mp3
- **Folder 3**

  - File 3.m4a

Mission accomplished.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rd /?`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it using two nested `for` loops, where the outer one iterates through the directories and the inner one iterates through the file types. The inner one iterates only in case at least one file of one of the predefined types, in which case a flag variable is set; after the inner loop, that flag is checked, and the directory removal is done conditionally:

```bat
for /D %%D in ("D:\root\*") do (
    set "FLAG="
    pushd "%%~D"
    for %%F in ("*.flac" "*.mp3" "*.m4a") do set "FLAG=#"
    popd
    if not defined FLAG rmdir /S /Q "%%~D"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a strange looking alternative.

In the case of your specific question, just make sure that your chosen parent directory and required extensions are input in the two variables on lines 3 and 4 respectively.

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "ParD=C:\Users\blazin8s\Main Directory"
Set "Exts=*.flac *.mp3 *.m4a"
For /D %%A In ("%ParD%\*") Do Call :Sub "%%~fA"
Timeout -1
Exit/B

:Sub
Set "i=0"
For /F "Tokens=1-3" %%A In ('RoboCopy %1 Null /E /LEV:1 /NFL /NDL /NJH /L %Exts%
') Do If %%B==: (Set/A "i+=1"
        If !i! Equ 2 If %%C Equ 0 Echo=RD/S/Q %1)
```

- The above can be altered too, first change `/E` to `/S` on line 11 *(optional)*, then:

  Change the second `Equ` on line 13 to `Gtr` to remove directories only containing any of your specified extensions. You could then possibly move only the directories containing any of your specified extensions by further changing `RD/S/Q` to `Move`.

  You could even change the original posting's line 13 from `0` to `4` to remove directories containing exactly 4 files matching any of your specified extensions.

**Note** - In all cases, the script will only show you what would happen. If you're happy with that output then remove `Echo=` from line 13 and either remove `-` from line 6 or all of line 6.